# kendo ui grid not working with .net core

Tags: postgresql, kendo-ui, asp.net-core

I am trying to get Kendo UI grid MVC working in a .net core, reading data from PostgreSQL database.

I set up a project, connected it to a database, scaffolded controller with appropriate views and it's working ok (meaning CRUD operations are working ok).
Now I want to hook it up with Kendo.
I followed guide from [kendo website](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/mvc-core/getting-started) and installed successfully (although it didn't offer pro version in nugget so I had to install trial??). I added all those CSS/js files in _Layout.cshtml

this is my code in controller:

```
        public ActionResult kendo()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET for Kendo
    public ActionResult Categories_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(GetCategories().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        var result = from c in _context.Categories
                     select new Category()
                     {
                         Id = c.Id,
                         Name = c.Name
                     };

        return result;
    }
```

this is my code in kendo.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Category>()
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Title("id");
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
})
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .Refresh(true)
    .PageSizes(true)
    .ButtonCount(5))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("Categories_Read", "Categories"))
    .PageSize(20)
)
```

Model is simple

```
    public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that there is no data displayed in kendo grid. I can see in debugger that there is request going forward and data coming backwards but nothing is shown in grid.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most probably caused by the [new ASP.NET Core serialization mechanism](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194). Follow the guidelines in the "second" **Step 4** here:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/mvc-core/getting-started

> Step 4 Open Startup.cs, using a text editor (IDE) and update it as described below.
>
> Locate the ConfigureServices method and add a call to services.AddKendo at the end.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // Maintain property names during serialization. See:
    // https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());

    // Add Kendo UI services to the services container
    services.AddKendo();
}
```

> Locate the Configure method and add a call to app.UseKendo at the end.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...

    // Configure Kendo UI
    app.UseKendo(env);
}
```

**UPDATE**

In order to verify that the above configuration is applied, check the server response and see if it has the following structure and letter casing for Data and Total:

```
{
    "Data": [
        { "Id": "1", "Name": "Name 1" },
        { "Id": "2", "Name": "Name 2" }
    ],
    "Total": "2"
}
```

Comment: thanks, i missed that one line 
'.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a .net core 3.1 project, the solution here is to add the following lines in Startup.cs:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });

services.AddKendo();
```